# Java: How to merge and cut H.264 mp4 files with ffmpeg

Tags: java, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, mp4parser

I wrote an java application to handle my GoPro video data. Recording for a couple of hours the GoPro produces several chapters (mp4-files). Now the program is able to cut out a sequence no matter if it is in just one chapter or it touches more. I execute the outstanding tool ffmpeg.exe with the Processbuilder.
First the program exports the mp4-files to *.ts-files and then it merges it togehter to one only mp4-file. At least a sequence will be cut out of this merged mp4-file using ffmpeg.exe for the second time. It works quite reliable and quickly.

But: I do not have one application in its entirely, but also I have two files (jar-Application and ffmpeg.exe). I think there is are java-libraries of ffmpeg but I do not know how to include and how to use them. I am just searching for a one-file-solution.

Do you know which library I need and where I can download it? How may I have to use it? If that is not possible, do you know some other user-friendly libraries doing the same job with less lines of code? How to use them?

I am very grateful about your help and the examples you will give!

Comment: What is it that you want to do here? Merge FFmpeg.exe and your JAR into a single executable?

Comment: Does it mean, that I have to extract ffmpeg.exe of the jar and then I run it? That would also be a solution. How to do it? I tried to implement it, but I did not succeed.

Comment: You can build a jar, and create a self-extracting archive using some tool.

Comment: That is exactly, what I tried. But it does not work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677427/java-how-to-includ-an-exe-file-into-jar-and-run-it